# Make right-Super act like Control in Kubuntu on Macbook

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, mac, macbook, shortcut-keys

I have just installed Kubuntu 22.04 on a Macbook Air and have noticed that the keyboard has two Super/Meta keys but just one (left) control. I am more familiar with PC keyboards: I don't need two Super keys, but I need two Ctrl keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do given that the advanced keyboard settings contain an option to "Swap right Win with Right Ctrl".

[image]

The same must be available in Gnome and Mate.